# call a method into another class whenever a button is pressed

Tags: class, button

I have 2 classes:

- Class `X` contains the method `listObjects();`
- and class `Y` is the GUI class and it contains the Button List.

What I want is, whenever the button list in the class `Y` is clicked, I want the method `listObjects();` from class `X` get executed and the output is displayed in the txtfield called `txtfieldList`.

I have included the following code in the class under the button List

```
X  x = new X (); // create an instance of the class X in the GUI class
txtfieldList.setText(x.list()); // execute the method list from class X and display the output in the tstfield
```

but the error I am getting is:

> the method setText(string) in the type JTextComponent is not
>   applicable for the argument (void)

Could some one help to figure out where the mistake is ?

Comment: What language are we talking about? Java?

Comment: hope you are taking about Java Swing. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the return type of the method listObjects() or list() is void. I hope your method signature is like this:

```
public void listObjects(){}
```

here this method returns nothing, so when you call this method inside setText("text"), the error appears because setText takes a string as parameter.

try like this:

```
public String listObjects(){
String str="text";
return str;
}
```